# Python: cutting out the outer frame of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working with a `numpy` array storing climate data over a certain region. The array has the following sizes:

```
data.shape[0]=365, data.shape[1]=466 #y,x
```

Let's say I want to create a new array by cutting out the outer frame of `data`, e.g. eliminating the values in an outer frame of `width=5`. The new array would have the following dimensions:

```
new.shape[0]=355, new.shape[1]=456 #y,x
```

My current array is in the form:

```
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ],
       ..., 
       [ 17.00830078,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,  28.21435547,
         28.28242111,  28.33056641],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,  28.25419998,
         28.32392502,  28.34052658],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,  28.23759842,
         28.31396484,  28.36874962]], dtype=float32)
```

How could this be implemented in Python?

Comment: can't you just do `data[5:data.shape[0]-5, 5:data.shape[1]-5]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [`slice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) -

```
c = 5  # No. of elems to be cropped on either sides
cropped_out = a[c:-c,c:-c]
```

Sample run -

```
In [212]: a
Out[212]: 
array([[2, 8, 4, 1, 4, 2, 0, 1, 6, 1],
       [4, 0, 2, 8, 0, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5],
       [5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4, 1, 7],
       [6, 8, 2, 4, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2],
       [6, 2, 5, 1, 1, 3, 7, 3, 3, 5],
       [4, 8, 4, 5, 6, 8, 6, 1, 0, 7],
       [7, 2, 8, 8, 6, 7, 3, 1, 7, 2]])

In [213]: c = 2 # No. of elems to be cropped on either sides

In [214]: a[c:-c,c:-c]
Out[214]: 
array([[6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4],
       [2, 4, 3, 0, 3, 0],
       [5, 1, 1, 3, 7, 3]])
```